# error: expected initializer before `extern` on GCC libraries

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to build code on another system. Machine A builds the code Machine B does not. Machine B needed updated to GCC 6.1.0 in order to compile said code. The update was handled exactly the same as Machine A's upgrade to GCC 6.1.0. I need to build several applications and they all output a similar error when building on Machine B:

```
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:375:0,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:25,
                 from app.h:12,
                 from app.c:28:
/usr/include/sys/types.h:27:1: error: expected initializer before 'extern'
 __BEGIN_DECLS
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/new:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/string:41,
                 from ./Lib/Inc/AppCommon.h:11,
                 from ./Lib/Inc/header0.h:10,
                 from ./Lib/Inc/header1.h:4,
                 from ./Lib/Inc/header2.h:10,
                 from app.c:30:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/exception:35:37: error: expected declaration before end of line
 #pragma GCC visibility push(default)
                                     ^
```

This error is not present on Machine A when building the applications. Is this a problem with GCC libraries? What differences between the environments, that I might not be accounting for, cause such an error? Could this have to do with the order files that need to be included in the build command; would this be different on different machines of the same environment?

Comment: You probably have an error in your source file `app.c` or the header file `app.h`.

Comment: ... to bad we can't see those files. `AppCommon.h`, `header0.h` etc. are also likely culprits.

Comment: That was my thought, but I'm using the same exact files on another machine to build the same application, and it doesn't present this error at all

Comment: Without seeing any code we can only guess what the problem is. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The application code is MatLab Autocode, and as previously mentioned the code is exactly the same on another machine that builds successfully; with the same gcc version

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your code is exactly the same then something in the toolchain is probably different (even though you followed the same upgrade procedure). Anyway, we can't help you with what we don't see.